# Printing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I know how to invoke the print dialog and do other things. My question is : what is the best practice to print a WPF page.

1. To invoke another page with all
   margins, formatting and layout worked
   out. And then call the print on that
2. To invoke a user control with all
   margins, formatting and layout worked
   out. And then call the print on that
3. To invoke a window with all
   margins, formatting and layout worked
   out. And then call the print on that
4. Or any other preferred way of
   doing this.

Please let me know how you approach printing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In WPF you have many options to print. The question which one is best suited dependes IMO extremely on the content to be printed and the desired quality.

**Printing visual**
If ouy want to print something that looks exactly like the representation in the UI, then you could try printing directly the visual that builds the root-content of your print-content. If you have positioning problems and have to correct properties of this visual, I would recommend to created a memory-copy of it, transform the copy and then print out this copy. Printing out visuals has IMO many drawbacks. I seldom use it except for short hacks and mini-tools. If I use, I mostly have to create the mentioned invisible copy and print out this. If you go this way, take care that you have to call Measure and [Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx) from code.

**Printing FlowDocument**
Another possiblity is to print out a FlowDocument. If you have something that fits into [FlowDocuments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx), I find this an easy way to create nice content to print out. Mostly if you have some simple reports, list ith some images, this way is a nice way. The print-quality is good and many complex operations will be done for you automatically as long as you don't want to override behaviour, and also this is possible. The quality of such print-out's is IMO very good.

**XPS Printing**
Hovever if you have complex content and you want it to print out nicely, you have to build XPS-content and print it over the [XPS Print Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418.aspx#XPS_print_path_intro). This way, you have all possibilities and options, the qualitity is very good but you have the most work to do. I don't like it much, but mostly it's the way I take to print.

I assume, that your question mainly concerns the first block, however I think it could be helpfull to see which options you have, if printing the visual is not enought (for me it's very seldom enough). Hope this answers your question.

Comment: ***Right now i am Printing this way :*** I am creating a page of width="800" and Height="1300" (according to printer page) with all the margins and layout as per the printing requirements.... Then i am calling the PrintVisual for the page.... I guess the better approach will be to use XPS and IMO, right ??

Comment: @HCL: The technically better solution must not always be the best solution. It dependes on what the clients wants and what the client is ready to pay for it. If the result looks like it has to, why make a more complex solution? Also is it important that you are satisfied with the result. If it's not for a client, why not invest into XPS. However I must admit that printing is not my beloved topic. I have not seen any printing plattform I liked. But this is my personal feeling and maybe there exist people loving programming printing code much more than creating nice GUIs or cool data-layers :)

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay: No there is no need to create a file. The documentation is maybe a little confusing because it's a broad topic. I have googled quickly for a howto: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/wpf-printing-part-2-the-fixed-document.aspx You will find a lot more if you google for [WPF Printing FixedDocument]

Comment: @HCL : Thanks .....Actually i am reading msdn documentation, a book on wpf and online samples at the same time, so misreading a lot......Will go through the topic in detail to learn all the options available... :-)

Comment: @HCL "Printing out visuals has IMO many drawbacks" Do you have a link regarding this topic or can you elaborate further? I'm just considering printing of visuals since I found many obstacles regarding look and styling when I used FlowDocuments.

Comment: @Amenti: Yes, FlowDocuments are very specific. I like them but if you want to have full-control, XPS print path is IMO the only way to go. Sadly I can’t give you hard facts at this time, it's too much time since I have written the last WPF print code. But I remember that I always felt very limited in printing visuals and always if I had to do some bigger print-outs (paginated and nicely formated), I landed on the XPS print path. Sorry to be not able to give you a more profound answer.

Comment: @HCL No problem. Thanks for answering. I'll research this some more.

Comment: I asked a separate question regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964349/wpf-silverlight-printing-of-visuals-drawbacks