# WPF/Silverlight: Printing of Visuals - Drawbacks

Tags: wpf, silverlight, printing

I read once or twice that printing visuals from WPF/Silverlight has some drawbacks so people usually tend to use FlowDocument or FixedDocument for printing.

I want to print some graphically intense dashboards and printing the visual directly seems to be the easiest way to go. I don't have to care about pagination since every dashboard I want to print is supposed to fit on one page.

Are there still drawbacks I must consider before choosing this way of printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print Visual objects by hosting them in a FrameworkElement and then adding the FrameworkElement to a FixedDocument as content of a FixedPage.  The Visual host looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements a FrameworkElement host for a Visual
/// </summary>
public class VisualHost : FrameworkElement
{
    Visual _visual;


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of visual children (always 1)
    /// </summary>
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="visual">The visual to host</param>
    public VisualHost(Visual visual)
    {
        _visual = visual;

        AddVisualChild(_visual);
        AddLogicalChild(_visual);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get the specified visual child (always
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Index of visual (should always be 0)</param>
    /// <returns>The visual</returns>
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index out of range");
        return _visual;
    }
}
```

Then you can add them and print them like this:

```
        // Start the fixed document
        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        Point margin = new Point(96/2, 96/2);      // Half inch margins

        // Add the visuals
        foreach (Visual nextVisual in visualCollection)
        {
            // Host the visual
            VisualHost host = new VisualHost(nextVisual);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            Canvas.SetLeft(host, margin.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(host, margin.Y);
            canvas.Children.Add(host);

            // Make a FixedPage out of the canvas and add it to the document
            PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
            FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
            fixedPage.Children.Add(canvas);
            ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
            fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
        }

        // Write the finished FixedDocument to the print queue
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
        xpsDocumentWriter.Write(fixedDoc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. But my question is really more about real world experience with this kind of printing. What problems will arise, will I have to bang my head against the wall more than usually and so on.

Comment: There are no drawbacks that I've encountered.  I've used the method above to print pages filled with WPF objects, and I've also used it to print incredibly complex drawings with thousands of lines and filled areas using DrawingVisual.